# Why getBoundingClientRect is not returning new value after resize

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to calculate the distance from X-axis for two elements, like this:

```js
return (
  this.toggleButtonElement.getBoundingClientRect().top -
  offsetElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
);
```

The problem is that when the window is resized I get the previous value (e.g. from portrait mode, and the expected value is to be calculated from the new distance regarding landscape mode and vice-versa). But if I scroll a little the correct value is calculated regarding the new screen size. This value is calculated when the component is initialized, the window is resized or when the user scroll.

Example: 
Portrait mode 
`toggleButton top > 968
offsetElement bottom > 407`
After resize on landscape mode:
`toggleButton top > 956
offsetElement bottom > 407`
After a little scroll on landscape mode:
`toggleButton top > 712
offsetElement bottom > 407`
I except to get the last value when the window is resized. Also I tried to delay the resize execution with even 10 seconds, but the result is the same.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Nope, sorry. It is a private project.

Comment: If it possible ,,can create stack blitz for part of code which is not working?

Comment: What if you add `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` before trying to get the values? Also, how did you query for `toggleButtonElement` in your component?

Comment: I found a workaround but I don't like it, triggering a new resize event.
The `toggleButtonElement` is queried with `document.querySelector()`.
But how `changeDetection` can help in this case? I don't change any data.

Comment: @AndreiGătej thank you! The problem was solved by injecting ElementRef in the component where I need to calculate all those things and querying elements from that reference. So please, if you want to post an answer and I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it worked! Mentioning `changeDetectionRef` was a little redundant, I mixed up your case with a former one of mine. That indeed included some property changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matters how you query for that element.

Make sure you inject the element using [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef).